# Drawing a surface with x,y,z points

Tags: matlab, plot

I have a list of `x`, `y`, `z` in this form:

```
   -0.2894    1.2835    0.5405
   -0.8171   -0.3034    0.1824
    2.7864    0.5506    0.0037
```

I could plot using `plot3(x,y,z, '*')` and it works fine.

Now I would like to draw a surface, but when I do:

```
>> surf(x,y,z)
??? Error using ==> surf at 78
Z must be a matrix, not a scalar or vector.
```

How should I draw it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suggest you do a Delaunay triangulation of the x,y values, and then use z as height for a surface plot:

```
x = randn(100,1);
y = randn(100,1);
z = (exp(-x.^2-y.^2));
tri = delaunay(x,y);
trisurf(tri,x,y,z)
```

[image]

**EDIT**

Since you seem to have problems with your Matlab version, here's an alternative: use `griddata` to interpolate your data onto a regular grid, so that you can use `surf` for plotting.

```
x = randn(100,1);
y = randn(100,1);
z = (exp(-x.^2-y.^2));
[xx,yy]=meshgrid(-2:0.1:2,-2:0.1:2);
zz = griddata(x,y,z,xx,yy);
dfig,surf(xx,yy,zz)
```

[image]

Comment: Interesting. When I run `tri = delaunay(x,y);` matlab crashes. Any idea?

Comment: @Macarse: is that on my example or on your data? Also: What kind of crash? CTD? Segfault? Error?

Comment: It also happens with you example :( I actually don't know which type of error it throws, it just closes. Which version are you using?

Comment: @Macarse: That is weird (i.e. seems like it could be a Matlab bug). It runs on 2012a without problems. What version are you using?

Comment: I a, running it in MATLAB 7.10.0 (R2010a) in a macos computer

Comment: @Macarse: Wasn't that when they started dropping xterm? That was quite a buggy time. Anyway, I've added an alternative way for surface plotting.

Comment: This also fails with my example data but your example does work. I guess I will try to get a newer version! Thanks for your reply.

Comment: @Macarse: Sorry to hear that your data fails even with the alternative solution (did you use good limits with the `meshgrid` command?). Anyway, in my experience, 64-bit Matlab on OSX became usable in 2011.

Comment: I guess I did but even if I did it wrong the app should crash like this :(. I am getting a new version for sure.